# Function giving correct answer in one case, not in any others

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo, return

Below is the function I am using. It is strange because when I test the name "admin" it returns an associative array with all the correct columns and values, however every other name tests returns 0 as far as I can tell, meaning nothing is found from the query (I am entering the names perfectly as they are in the database).

I have a feeling this could be some sort of security feature of pdo or something but I don't understand why it is acting up this way.

I am using mysql.

Does anyone know the problem and how to resolve it? Thank you!

```
function getUserDetailsByName($name, $fields = "*")
{   
    $db = connect_db();

    $query = "SELECT $fields FROM UserDetails WHERE userName=:username";
    $result = $db->prepare($query);
    $result->bindParam(":username", $name);

    if (!($result->execute())) {
        sendMessage (1,1,'Query failed',$query);
        $db = null;
        return;
    }
    if (!($result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM) > 0)) {
        $db = null;
        return 0;
    }else{
        $result = $result->fetch();
        $db = null;
        return $result;
    }   
}
```

EDIT: Someone asked to post how I call the function.

```
$user = getUserDetailsByName($_POST['value']);
if($user == 0)
{
  print "user = 0";
}
print_r($user);
```

Comment: Please show how you are calling the function! Also, the `else` at the end is pointless. It's not like the previous `if + return` will get beyond the `return`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function getUserDetailsByName($name, $fields = "*"){
    $db = connect_db();

    $query = "SELECT {$fields} FROM UserDetails WHERE userName = :username LIMIT 1;";
    if(!$result = $db->prepare($query)){
        return null;
    }
    $result->bindParam(":username", $name);
    if(!$result->execute()) {
        sendMessage (1,1,'Query failed',$query);
        return null;
    }
    if(!$user = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {
        return false;
    }
    return $user;
}
```

**Why 2 fetches?** Checkout and compare this to your code.

Use like this:

```
if($user = getUserDetailsByName($_POST['value'])){
    // we have a user!
}else{
    // we don't have a user!
}
```

Comment: Ah ha, I didn't realise it was fetching the top value twice, I will edit this now and see if it makes a difference. Although I'm curious how it worked with one name and not another?

Comment: @AndrewB Duplicate DB records ?:) `admin` is twice in there.

Comment: @AndrewB Also keep in mind the `LIMIT 1` part. When you know you need just one record, it helps A LOT if MySQL knows that too.